# Error when trying to build with meta examples in shogun

Tags: cmake, shogun

I successfully built shogun without the examples ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783413/error-building-shogun-no-matching-function-for-call-to-pyunicode-asutf8andsize))  but now when I am trying to do the same with meta examples, I am getting an error as follows:

```
$ cmake -DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/swig -DINTERFACE_PYTHON=ON -DBUILD_META_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- Could NOT find CCache (missing: CCACHE CCACHE_VERSION)
-- Using system's malloc
CMake Error at src/shogun/CMakeLists.txt:49 (MESSAGE):
Shogun can only be built with GPL codes if the source files are in
/Users/krishna/shogun/src/gpl. Please download or disable with
LICENSE_GPL_SHOGUN=OFF.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/krishna/shogun/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/4179

Sorry I made a silly mistake as can be seen by the link.